# Integrating CKEDITOR into textarea

Tags: ckeditor

I am not able to integrate CKEDITOR into textarea. The following are the codes:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="localhost/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body bgcolor=Bisque>

    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="body" name="body">
    Hii
    </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace('body');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check for errors in console. That might give u a hint.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju: I have checked console errors. These are fine.

Comment: Do you really have a folder `localhost` ?

Comment: @Wizard: No I do not

Answer (score 0):

Since you reported that you don't have a folder `localhost`, the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="localhost/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

is wrong. The browser is trying to load `ckeditor.js` from a folder `localhost` in the same directory level with your page. I presume that the folder `ckeditor` is inside your server root folder, so use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```